# queryselector for a class button

Tags: queryselector

I have `<button class="btn btn-primary w-100 w-md-25">Submit</button>`

and I want to put the button on the below queryselector.

```
(document.querySelector(".form.row.pt-4 button[type='submit']")) {
                    document.querySelector(".form.row.pt-4 button[type='submit']").addEventListener("click", function() {
```

How to code the button correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to put an event listener on the button, you could do it like this:

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // do something here
});
```

Bear in mind that this selector '.btn' will select all elements with that class and `querySelector` will select the first instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your button an id so you can trigger the button separatly.
`<button id="mySubmitButton1" class="btn btn-primary w-100 w-md-25">Submit</button>`

use the jquery framework in your JS than you can establish sth like this...
`$("#mySubmitButton1").click(function(){ sth... });`
see [jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/click/)